# Why won't my Lightning Component Attributes store entered value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service, aura-attribute

**2/15/2017 Update**

Per comment from Doug in one of the answers this is an issue with Locker service. I verified that with Locker **disabled** is works as expected...

In Spring 17 as of today, with locker **enabled** it is still not working however

**Update**

So, since we get an internal error when passing classes/objects to apex controllers AND if values are not set in the controller when the component requests them then there is no way to pass those properties back (see below), I am left with this mess for every non string property

```
    @AuraEnabled public String endDate {
        get {
            return endDate == null ? '' : endDate;
        }
        set;
    }
    private date endDateValue {
        get {
            if (string.isBlank(endDate)) return null;

            return date.valueOf(endDate);
        }
        set {
            if (value == null) endDate = null; else endDate = string.valueOf(value);

        }
    }
```

Should not have to go through all that to use a simple class property in a component...Ugh

**Original discussion**

So I have been fighting with this for a while. Maybe my mindset is wrong and what I am doing is correct but it just seems like a lot of extra work.

**Scenario**

1. Component with attribute set to a type of a custom class
2. Input boud to a property in that class

Now is it too much to as that when the data is entered in the input that it is reflected in the component? The actual input keeps the value but the attribute is never set....

It makes it extremely difficult to pass data around. Right not I am manually setting the attribute properties based on the value input in the component.

So the examples:

The first input when data is input always logs as:

> {}

The second input the data logs correctly when value are input into the field.

[image]

The weird part is that accessing the actual property outputs as expected:

```
console.log(component.get('v.myCustomClass.myTestString'));
```

outputs

> a

as shown in the second debug line in the image

[image]

**Custom Class**

```
public class myProblemClass {
    @AuraEnabled public string myTestString {get;set;}

    public myProblemClass(){

    }

    public myProblemClass(String setDefault){
        mytestString = setDefault;
    }
}
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public class myProblemController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static myProblemClass newProblemClass(){
        return New myProblemClass();
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static myProblemClass newProblemClassInitial(){
        return New myProblemClass('initial');
    }

}
```

**Lightning Component**

```
<aura:component description="myProblemComponent" controller="myProblemController">

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="myCustomClass" type="myProblemClass"/>
    <aura:attribute name="myCustomClassInitial" type="myProblemClass"/>

                <div class="slds-form-element">
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-01">Input Label</label>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <ui:inputText aura:id="firstInput" updateOn="keyup" keyup="{!c.logMe}" requiredIndicatorClass="slds-required"
                                      required="true" value="{!v.myCustomClass.myTestString}" placeholder="Enter Me"
                                      class="slds-input"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="slds-form-element">
                    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-01">Input Label</label>
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                        <ui:inputText updateOn="keyup" keyup="{!c.logMe}" requiredIndicatorClass="slds-required"
                                      required="true" value="{!v.myCustomClassInitial.myTestString}" placeholder="Enter Me"
                                      class="slds-input"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

</aura:component>
```

**Component Controller**

```
({
    doInit: function (component, event, helper) {

        var action = component.get("c.newProblemClass");
        var actionInitial = component.get("c.newProblemClassInitial");

        action.setCallback(this, function (response){
            component.set('v.myCustomClass',response.getReturnValue());
        })

        actionInitial.setCallback(this, function (response){
            component.set('v.myCustomClassInitial',response.getReturnValue());
        })

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        $A.enqueueAction(actionInitial);

    },
    logMe: function(component,event,helper){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(component.get('v.myCustomClass')));
        console.log(component.get('v.myCustomClass.myTestString'));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(component.get('v.myCustomClassInitial')));
    }
})
```

Now, I get that in the first attribute that I am not setting the value of the class property thus the Java object does not contain anything. However, when I set a value in the first Input that is Bound to the class property I would expect it to set it.

The questions:

1. Are my expectations incorrect
2. If #1 is true then is setting the value of the attribute as follows the correct way. Keeping in mind my real class has 20-30 properties so that is a lot of extra code to write just to set the values

   ```
    component.get('v.myCustomClass').myTestString = 
         component.find('firstInput').get('v'value');
   ```

So as Ashwani points out, the binding of the value on the input get set properly so you can access the property directly. So why does it still output as `{}` when logging the attribute.

Now if I do this:

```
    component.get('v.myCustomClass').myTestString = 'ABCDEF';
    console.log(JSON.stringify(component.get('v.myCustomClass')));
```

then JSON of the attribute outputs the correct JSON string (see 4th debug line). So I can set it in the JS but there is no way to set it in using the actual Input field?? But you can access the property directly when set by the input field `v.myCustomClass.mytestString`....Confusing.....

[image]

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand your question properly. Did you mean that when the component loads, in the second input box "Initial" value is not prepopulated?

Comment: No, when you type values in the first box it does not get set in the attribute. When you type values in the second box the attribute updates. Would like to have the attribute update without have to initialize all properties in the class to an empty string

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(component.get('v.myCustomClassInitial')));` is working fine for me

Comment: @Ashwani - yup, the initial one works, the non initial does not. thats what I showed in my example. I do not expect to have to do it like the initial bu setting empty string for all properties in the class.

Comment: This is interesting, when I am logging "component.get('v.myCustomClass.myTestString')", it gives the value a, however when logging the class, it returns empty. Let me have a look.

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty you are correct, I just verified that. Wierd

Comment: You will have to define it because Lightning doesn't know if there is such property exist on not (it is undefined). Because of locker service it won't even let you defined new property.

Comment: @Ashwani - May be correct, but accessing the property directly via `console.log(component.get('v.myCustomClass.myTestString'));` does output `a` where just using `v.mycustomClass` outputs `{}`. Something weird here

Comment: There is a framework logic. Only you know there is `myCustomClass.myTestString` but framework doesn't know. Take the example: set the input as ` <ui:inputText aura:id="firstInput" updateOn="keyup" keyup="{!c.logMe}" requiredIndicatorClass="slds-required"
                                      required="true" value="{!v.myCustomClass.myTestStringNOOOOO}" placeholder="Enter Me"
                                      class="slds-input"/>` and access it as `console.log( component.get('v.myCustomClass.myTestStringNOOOOO'));` You will get the value but it is not the variable in controller.

Comment: @Ashwani - Yea, I get `1.1 undefined`. It does not give met the value of the input. When accessing as in my question anything I enter in the input gets output properly when accessing the property directly but when accessing just the class it gets {}

Comment: @Eric may be a typo mistake as I edited the comment multiple time because of trailing `OOO`. Try the example in my answer. it works

Comment: Ahh I see... You would think if the property is set the it would at least output when JSON the attribute....Especially if you can access it directly

Comment: This will not work "console.log(component.get('v.myCustomClass).myTestString));

Comment: @Ashwani No but `console.log(component.get('v.myCustomClass.myTestString));` does. And if I set the value using `component.get('v.myCustomClass').myTestString = 'xyz'` then the `JSON.stringify(component.get('v.myCustomClass');` works properly. That should be no different than binding it to the input IMHO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code is working as expected.

In the above approach there is  basic problem. Lightning does not initialize any variable itself.

In controller `testString` is not defined so, it is not even getting set and result `{}`:-

```
public class myProblemClass {
    @AuraEnabled public string myTestString {get;set;}

    public myProblemClass(){
    }

    public myProblemClass(String setDefault){
        mytestString = setDefault;
    }
}
```

Define variable in no argument constructor and it will start working:-

```
public myProblemClass(){
   mytestString = '';
}
```

There is a framework logic. Only you know there is myCustomClass.myTestString but framework doesn't know.

Take the example: set the input as:

```
 <ui:inputText aura:id="firstInput" updateOn="keyup" keyup="{!c.logMe}" requiredIndicatorClass="slds-required"
                                      required="true" value="{!v.myCustomClass.myTestStringNOTEXIST}" placeholder="Enter Me"
                                      class="slds-input"/>
```

and access it as

```
console.log( ' 1.1 '+component.get('v.myCustomClass.myTestStringNOTEXIST'));
```

You will get the value but it is not the variable in controller.

Comment: then why does `console.log(component.get('v.myCustomClass.myTestString'));` work without initialization

Comment: Your last example confuses. It does not output the value entered in the input like in my question it outputs undefined

Comment: Hope you are clear @Eric :)

Comment: @Ashwany - nope. I see what you are doing. but if I can access it via directly then it should stringify with the class. If I do a `component.get('v.myCustomClass').mytestString = xyz` then the stringify works properly. That should be no different that binding it to the input

Comment: @Eric you are expecting result as native javascript does but here framework plays the role. You won't get `myTestString` even the `myTestStringNOTEXIST`. However, I am not much clear how framework is securing elements. I am seeing this behavior from the initially ExpenseTracker app to learn lightning was introduced. Now we have LockerService also.

Comment: I fail to see why the input does not update the attribute. Why does one have to set it only is JS if you want to pass the class to the apex controller, especially when you can access the property directly. This makes Lightning components useless for collecting data as you have to access the elements individually to get the values to set in the attributes to pass to the controller. Whats the point. If I have an attribute bound to the input it should set the value. Just like it does if I set the value directly in the JS. Seems like a bug in the UI and Lightning input components

Comment: @Eric I agree with you. My though is they are doing this to strict the data set between client and controller so no one can miss use or manipulate it. Because javascript has option to define properties at runtime even you can register functions whenever you want. This can break the secure environment of Salesforce where we can have several components from different vendors in a single page.

Comment: Ok, My main goal here is to understand if setting the values with 20-30 additional lines of code is the correct way of doing it. It seems like it is. So in my JS I am getting the value from the input and directly setting the properties of the attribute then sending the JSON result to the Apex controller.  Thanks for the time you put into this.....

Comment: Please retry your example with Locker deactivated in your org and let me know if you see a difference in behavior. There is a long standing issue/limitation in how Locker "wraps" plain old JavaScript objects that is actively being worked on but the solution requires the use of Proxy which was not available in a number of browsers until recently so we had to use a polyfil that is not entirely accurate. The plan is to complete the current work to leverage Proxy and release it to Soring'17 as a patch.

Comment: @DougChasman - Sorry for the Delay. I disabled Locker service and it DOES work as expected. I am now on Spring 17 and with locker Enabled it still does not work. With Locker disabled on Spring 17 it does work. Can you please post as an answer (maybe with expected resolution) so i can accept.

Answer (score 6):

This issue is currently scheduled to be fixed in the Summer '17 release by leveraging Proxy as Doug mentioned in the comments to another answer. I've verified the fix with a very similar scenario on the Summer '17 codeline. Unfortunately, the fix is not scheduled to be patched in to Spring '17 as initially hoped for.

Comment: What kind of timeline is this going to give us for testing between the release of this fix and the force enabling of Locker Service?

Comment: @D.S. Safe Harbor - we are working on a new rollout plan to protect existing production customer from breaking. Details coming out in next couple of weeks. Stay tuned.