# LockerService: When is an object wrapped in a Proxy? Why are standard functions removed?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I have a helper component that acts like an API by exposing some repetitive functionality via `<aura:method />`. As a parameter to one `<aura:method />` I accept an `options` argument of type `Object`. One of the properties of this object is an `Aura.Action`. Most of the time this works perfectly and I can call `setParams()` on that action. However, in some components the `options` parameter is being wrapped in a `Proxy`. This proxy seems to strip out the functions from the `Aura.Action` so that running `typeof options.action.setParams` returns `undefined`.

Is this intentional LockerService behavior? If so, why aren't all of my invocations of this method having the `options` parameter converted to a Proxy and how are we supposed to pass an `Aura.Action` so that we can still access its built in functions?

**Method**:

```
<aura:method name="call" action="{!c.executeApex}" access="PUBLIC">
    <!-- options properties

          options.component   {Aura.Component}  A reference to the invoking component
          options.action      {Aura.Action}     A reference to the action to be invoked
          options.params      {Object}          Action parameters
          options.storable    {Boolean}         If true, the action will be added to the cache
          options.onSuccess   {Function}        The function to invoke if the action is successful. The
                                                  function will be passed the invoking component and
                                                  server return value.
          options.onError     {Function}        The function tok invoke if the action is an error. The
                                                  function will be passed the invoking component and
                                                  error message as a string (if it exists).
          options.loader      {Object}          The loader configuration to show while waiting for
                                                  the server response. If null no loader will show.
            loader.title      {String}          The title to display under the loader.
            loader.subtitle   {String}          The subtitle to display under the loader.
            loader.fixed      {Boolean}         If true the loader will be fixed to the center of the
                                                  screen.

    -->
  <aura:attribute name="options" type="Object" />
</aura:method>
```

**Method usage**:

```
component.find('apexService').call({
  component: component,
  action: component.get('c.serverAction'),   
  onSuccess: function(result) {
    component.set('v.value', result);
  },
  storable: true
});
```

Comment: you might want to check this out [How LockerService Uses the Proxy Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_proxy.htm)

Comment: @glls Thanks for the link. I don't fall into any of those scenarios since I am in my own namespace here and am just passing to an aura:method, but they did qualify that list with "Some" meaning that there must be more. It's just really weird to me that this is only happening in some of my components where other components work fine when using the method in the exact same way. I am also not clear on why they would filter out their own built-in API methods on the Action object.

Comment: @dsharrison, as you describe the problem, you should not get this issue. I have replicated your code, and I get the right answer. Could you also post how you retrieve the `options` in the `executeApex` component controller?

Comment: @JFParadis thanks for trying to reproduce this. It turns out there was one important difference regarding API versions with the components that were experiencing the issue and I have detailed it below. It would be awesome if the documentation could be updated to include this case in the list of scenarios where the framework converts an Object to a filtered Proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is one more important scenario to add to the list of scenarios when an object is proxied in the Salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_proxy.htm). If a component is on API version < 39 and passes an object to the method of a component on API version >= 39, the arguments are filtered and passed as a Proxy.

The reason only a few of our components were experiencing this behaviour is that they were all using an additional helper to actually invoke the method and that helper component is set to API version 38 (due to another [issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164234/locker-service-cannot-set-field-values-that-were-null-on-records-from-soql-or-s)). Changing the API version to 41 allows the object to be passed unfiltered (and as an Object instead of a Proxy).

If someone from Salesforce sees this it would be great to add this to the list of scenarios in the documentation because for anyone with some legacy code this can be a real pain to figure out.

***Edit with more details***

I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/dsharrison/56f1cc2d698398134a83295f7dc1230d) with components to reproduce. In my org I get the following output from it (API <= v39 is filtering the object and API >= v40 is not.)

[image: Screenshot of gist]

Comment: Thanks, I've pinged the document editors. Have you narrowed your issue to a communication between locker on/off?

Comment: This was uncovered in a project running up against a tight deadline so once the API version bump was found to fix the issue we moved on. Let me go back and make a gist to see if I can better isolate the issue. I'll post an update here.

Comment: Got it. I'll keep an eye on this so we can best support you here.

Comment: @JFParadis I have created a reduced test case for this and confirmed that the behavior indeed is dependent on Locker Service being enabled or disabled (API version 40 and 41 work, 38 and 39 do not). I will collect the components into a gist and post it here.

Comment: @JFParadis I just added a gist and screenshot to this answer.